# join 2 mysql tables and get the first and last date

Tags: mysql, sql, date, join

I have 2 mysql tables, one with the users details and the second with all the pages that the users saw (1:N)

```
TABLE "users"
id int(10) auto_increment primay
ip varchar(15)
lang char(2)
...

TABLE "pages"
id int(10) auto_increment primay
uid int(10) index
datetime datetime
url varchar(255)
```

I know is possibile to join the 2 tables, but i'm a little confused how to get the first and last datetime, and the first url from the "pages" table...

```
SELECT * FROM users, pages WHERE users.id = pages.uid
```

I think with GROUP BY / MIN(pages.datetime), MAX(pages.datetime) but I have no idea where to use it, and how I can get the first pages.url

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned you need to use `Group by` with  `MIN` & `MAX` aggregate function to find the first and last `datetime` per `user`.

Also don't use comma separated join syntax which is quite old and not much readable use proper `INNER JOIN` syntax

```
SELECT U.ID,
       MIN(pages.datetime) as First_date, 
       MAX(pages.datetime) as Last_date  
FROM users U
INNER JOIN  pages P
        ON U.id = P.uid
Group by U.ID
```

If you want to see the other information like first visited `url`,etc.. Then you can join above result to the main table to get the related information.

```
select A.uid,A.url First_URL,C.url as Last_url,First_date,Last_date  
from pages A
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT U.ID,
       MIN(pages.datetime) as First_date, 
       MAX(pages.datetime) as Last_date  
FROM users U
INNER JOIN  pages P
        ON U.id = P.uid
Group by U.ID
) B
ON  A.ID =B.ID 
and A.datetime  = B.First_date
INNER JOIN pages C
on  C.ID =B.ID 
and C.datetime  = B.Last_date
```

Comment: thanks, it's working, but it's very hard to add other fields like pages.url (to get the first page saw), count(*) (to get how many pages each user visited) i think in this case is easier to execute a separete query on each user